# I'm trying to find out a way to embed a .wav audio file into a c++ application so its a audio standalone program

Tags: c++, audio, wav

i know how to play a .wav file when its in the same directory but i need to figure out how to embed it into my application making it a single executable.

```
void playMusic() 
{
    PlaySound(TEXT("song.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME);
}
int main()
{
    playMusic();
    return 0;
}
```

This is what i have for opening the file and playing it any help would be greatly appreciated. i was thinking about maybe copying the file's source into the actual source of my program and writing the source to a temp file in the same directory but when i try to copy and paste the source its no longer recognized so i need to do some sort of conversion i'm assuming. lost at this point.

Comment: `PlaySound()` can play a WAV stored in the app's resources, using the `SND_RESOURCE` flag instead of `SND_FILENAME`. Use an `.rc`/`.res` file to create such an embedded resource while compiling the program

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Thank you very much i got it all figured out and working now.